# Ansible playbook to get mysql version else set default value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Playbook errors out because mysql service is not installed on remote host. I wish to capture `mysql --version` of remote hosts and append the value in jinja2 template.

***Playbook.yml***

```
   - name: Get MySQL version.
     command: 'mysql --version'
     ignore_errors: yes
     register: version
   - debug:
       msg:
       - "Version:  {{ version.stdout | default('no mysql installed') }}"
   - name: Create Html
     ignore_errors: yes
     template:
      src: /path/mysql.j2
      dest: /path/mysql.html
```

Making use of `ignore_errors` to avoid termination of playbook. However, I have noticed. if MySQL does not exists on remote host it simply skips those those.

**What I am looking for is - variable should be assigned a default value eg. "MySQL not installed" if `mysql --version` fails on remote host (i.e. MySQL is not present on remote host).**

**Error:** Unable to create the HTML from jinja2 template as  version.stdout value seems to empty thus j2 is unable to assign the value to table data. Is there a workaround where I can set value with desired string eg. "Not Installed".

```
TASK [Create Html] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following to prevent any command to fail. This will remove the requirement of `ignore_errors: True`. In this playbook for demo , I have checked the version of `mysql` and an imaginary tool called `non-existing-tool` version. You can check the debug output of the two registers.

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get MySQL version.
    shell: 'mysql --version 2>/dev/null && printf "" || printf  "mysql not installed\n"'
    register: version


  - debug:
     msg:
      - "Version:  {{ version.stdout }}"

  - name: Get non-existing stuff version.
    shell: 'non-existing-stuff  --version 2>/dev/null && printf "" || printf  "mysql not installed\n"'
    register: version2

  - debug:
     msg:
      - "Version2:  {{ version2.stdout }}"
```

Here is the above `playbook` command output:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get MySQL version.] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Version:  mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"
    ]
}

TASK [Get non-existing stuff version.] ******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Version2:  mysql not installed"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

To test this command behavior, manually run the following command on the hosts with and without `mysql` installed.

```
mysql --version 2>/dev/null && printf "" || printf  "mysql not installed\n"
```

Comment: I have updated my question with jinja2 code and your answer and have also added the error message. Looks like version.stdout is empty and thus it errors out as j2 is unable to set table data to empty string.

Comment: well , with the update you changed lot of things in the original question.

Comment: Yes, apologies for that. All I am looking for is a way to get rid of the empty string error I am appending to j2 file.

Comment: Thank you very much. The thought never crossed my mind that it can also be handled via shell commands. This is what I was looking for. Though just one thing. The final output of the table seems to take value "mysql not installed" even if the remote host has MySQL running i.e. for all host it show "mysql not installed". Probably my Jinja2 logic is incorrect maybe?

Comment: perhaps its due to your `jinja2` logic. you can validate shell command behavior by running `mysql --version 2>/dev/null && printf "" || printf  "mysql not installed\n"` manually

Comment: Yes, I have validated and the shell command works. But the same is giving "mysql not installed" while doing it form the playbook. Most likely jinja2 looping error.

Comment: I checked the ansible playbook output. And it shows 

ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": [
        "Version:  mysql not installed"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": [
        "Version:  mysql not installed"
    ]
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": [
        "Version:  mysql not installed"
    ]
}

Comment: Looks like it is not a jinja2 error after all version.stdout seems to be `mysql not installed` for all.

Comment: can you login to `host1` and try to check mysql version manually ? I have updated output from one of my node where mysql is installed. This means, there is something missing in the info provided.

Comment: by any chance you are setting the same variable again ? can you add entire playbook to help. what you are mentioning does not make much sense as the command is using trivial bash operators `||` and `&&`

Comment: Ahh my bad... `mysql --version2>/dev/null && printf "" || printf  "mysql not installed\n"` there was no space for stderr append. So it was returning default value. Fixed it. Appreciate all the help. Everything is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234099/discussion-between-roman95-and-p).